# How to use GROUP BY with subquery range?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm quite new here and I am tinkering with MYSQL to get a sort of pivot table.

For now I'm blocked here :

```
SELECT `range`,
   Sum(IF(`Vrange` = '< 5',1,0)) as `<5`,
   Sum(IF(`Vrange` = ' 5-10',1,0)) as `5-10`,
   Sum(IF(`Vrange` = ' 10-15',1,0)) as `10-15`,
   Sum(IF(`Vrange` = ' 15-20',1,0)) as `15-20`,
   Sum(IF(`Vrange` = ' 20-25',1,0)) as `20-25`,
   Sum(IF(`Vrange` = ' 20-25',1,0)) as `20-25`,
   Sum(IF(`Vrange` = '> 30',1,0)) as `>30`
FROM(
     select `Time`,`HDG`, `Vitesse`,
        case 
            when `HDG` between 1 and 90 then ' 0-90' 
            when `HDG` between 91 and 180 then ' 91-180' 
            when `HDG` between 181 and 270 then ' 181-270' 
        else '271-360' 
        end as `range`,
        case 
            when `Vitesse` between 0 and 5 then '< 5' 
            when `Vitesse` between 6 and 10 then ' 5-10' 
            when `Vitesse` between 11 and 15 then ' 10-15' 
            when `Vitesse` between 16 and 20 then ' 15-20' 
            when `Vitesse` between 21 and 25 then ' 20-25' 
            when `Vitesse` between 25 and 30 then ' 25-30' 
        else '> 30' 
        end as `Vrange`
     from DataPort 
     WHERE `Time` > now() - interval 1 day  
     ORDER BY `Time` DESC

)as SQ
GROUP BY `range`;
```

I get the following anwser :

```
|  range  |    <5   |    5-10    |   ...
|---------|---------|------------|--------
|   0-90  |     5   |     3      |
| 180-270 |     12  |     20     |
```

And I would like to display all items of range i.e. 0-90 / 91-180 / 181-270 / 271-360 in each row. How is it possible ? As follow :

```
|  range  |    <5   |    5-10    |   ...
|---------|---------|------------|--------
|   0-90  |     1   |     1      |
|  91-180 |0 or null| 0 or null  |
| 180-270 |     12  |     20     |
| 271-360 |0 or null| 0 or null  |
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: "...And I would like to display all items of..."  -- Please include a few rows of how the expected result should look.

Comment: so, a resultset that is 28 columns by 1 row?

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, post updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to S/O.  This should help get what you had going.  You did not need to do an explicit pre-query to get ranges, then sum again in the outer query for the counts.

```
select
        AllRanges.Required Range,
        sum( case when DP.Vitesse >= 0 and DP.Vitesse < 5 then 1 else 0 end ) ' < 5',
        sum( case when DP.Vitesse >= 5 and DP.Vitesse < 10 then 1 else 0 end ) '5-10',
        sum( case when DP.Vitesse >= 10 and DP.Vitesse < 15 then 1 else 0 end ) '10-15',
        sum( case when DP.Vitesse >= 15 and DP.Vitesse < 20 then 1 else 0 end ) '15-20',
        sum( case when DP.Vitesse >= 20 and DP.Vitesse < 25 then 1 else 0 end ) '20-25',
        sum( case when DP.Vitesse >= 25 and DP.Vitesse < 30 then 1 else 0 end ) '25-30',
        sum( case when DP.Vitesse >= 30 then 1 else 0 end ) '>30'
    from
        ( select '0-90' Required
          UNION select '91-180'
          UNION select '181-270'
          UNION select '271-360' ) AllRanges
            LEFT JOIN DataPort DP
                ON AllRanges.Required = 
                   case when DP.HDG >= 0 and DP.HDG <= 90 then '0-90'
                        when DP.HDG > 90 and DP.HDG <= 180 then '91-180'
                        when DP.HDG >= 180 and DP.HDG <= 270 then '181-270'
                        else '271-360' end
                   AND DP.`Time` > now() - interval 1 day 
    group by
        case when DP.HDG >= 0 and DP.HDG <= 90 then '0-90'
             when DP.HDG > 90 and DP.HDG <= 180 then '91-180'
             when DP.HDG >= 180 and DP.HDG <= 270 then '181-270'
             else '271-360' end
```

Now, having said that, and the above will work, I would like to point out some less-than-optimal parts of it.

Your "HDG", I believe is a directional Heading and will always be technically 0-359 degrees as 360 is actually back to 0.

In your Vitesse range brackets, and not knowing if any fractional / decimal values or not, but you are using the labels twice, such as `5-10` and `10-15`.  Shouldn't 10 only be within one of the brackets?  Your between was testing between 11 and 15, so shouldn't the header group also match?

Your result columns should be named columns.  Not spaces, and especially not special characters, dashes, etc.  The results should be a table with direct column names.  It is the part of your OUTPUT such as report or web that has heading columns with proper context rather than naming the columns as you were attempting.

Finally, careful on your column names, such as `'Time'`  Try NOT to use reserved keywords within your SQL table column definitions.  Take a look at the commands available, function names, etc.  Instead of just time, maybe a EntryTime, LogTime, CreateTime, or similar.  A bit more explicit context and you'll avoid having to add `tick` marks to everything.  Also, by qualifying with table.column or alias.column helps prevent ambiguity when joining to multiple tables having similar column names.

Just trying to suggest improvements for this and future as you grow with SQL.

**FEEDBACK**

As per issue of not getting all ranges, I have revised the query.  Notice the inner (select ---- ranges) AllRanges via LEFT JOIN to the DataPort table.  In this case, the primary table is now the `AllRanges` alias with 4 rows for each one you want.  THEN, I did the LEFT JOIN to the DataPort table.  The join is based on the condition of the AllRanges.Required column matching the conditional CASE --- PLUS the Time condition of the date.

If you have the WHERE clause for the time, it internally will convert the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN thus preventing all 4 ranges.

Should be good to go now.

Comment: Thanks for tips especially for `Time` and name columns.

Your solution works if I have values in all range of `HDG` (0 to 359°), otherwise I come back to my problem.  If I have only values from 0 to 89 and 180 to 270, is ti possible to have `91-180` and `271-359` with an empty row (all columns at 0 or null) ?

Comment: @LRZ_FRA, revised query and read feedback in answer to clarify

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if anything is wrong with your code... Are you saying you are missing "91-180" and "271"360"?
Are you sure you have rows that match that range in your subquery?

Comment: You are right, my subquery doesn't show "91-180" and "271"360" . Is it possible to get a 0 or null row in top query  using broup by `range` ?

Comment: Don't use the answer functionality to comment on the question.